# How to make values to be added automatically to a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am having 2 tables: Orders Table and Books Table. I enter some of the book details in the Orders table(such as name, publisher, author etc.), and i want this details to automatically be added to the Book table when i start to enter the book's details.

for example if i entered in the Orders table the details:

Name:Harry Potter

Author:J.K.Roliing

Year:2000

And then i write in the datagridview ,of the Books table, in the "Name" column of a new row "Harry Potter", i want the program automatically complete the author and year, by the values entered in the Orders table. 
I tried to use CellEndEdit event to achieve that, but when i write a book name in a new row, an error jumps, saying:"There is no row in position x".
Here is my Code:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string headerText = dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;//header of the column of the cell edited

        if (headerText.Equals("Name"))//if a Name cell was edited
        {

            string BookName = ds.Tables["Books"].Rows[e.RowIndex]["Name"].ToString();//get the name typed
            DataRow Order = FindRowByValue(BookName, "BooksOrders", "Name");//get the order details of the typed book

            ds.Tables["Books"].Rows[e.RowIndex]["Author"] = Order["Author"];//updating the book details as written in the order.
            ds.Tables["Books"].Rows[e.RowIndex]["Publishing"] = Order["Publishing"];
            ds.Tables["Books"].Rows[e.RowIndex]["Supplier"] = Order["Supplier"];
        }
```

thanks for everyone answering

Comment: Why are you putting book detail in the Orders table? You should really just use a book id.

Comment: This probelm is string BookName = ds.Tables["Books"].Rows[e.RowIndex]["Name"].ToString(). Because e.RowIndex >= ds.Tables["Books"].Rows.Count.